# Recommended development framework and DB for web app with the following characteristics

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will shortly be looking for a technical partner to build my business to business  productivity tool but want to ensure we are using the right framework to ensure a great user experience. I have researched myself but I am still really not sure what kind of framework best suits my needs. So maybe there are people out there that could give me pointers!

At the moment I am looking at a combination of Ruby On rails, HTML5, CSS and MySQL

The key characteristics of the project are: 
- it is a business to business web application based on projects, admins and users
- you can create a "project" that can be responded to by a number of different users
- each project can have:
           - ability to manage, preview and embed business documents e.g. word, pdfs etc.
           - action buttons that allows comments, approvals etc to be carried out
           - ability to create simple forms with text fields, radio buttons etc.
           - ability to drag and drop options from a menu to include in the process e.g. a blank text box

Comment: Rails is a great fit, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is a good fit for such projects . You will have write less code , easy to manage , lots of plugins that will help you do most of the things .